# Why does this function in NextJS works locally, but not when deployed in AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, next.js, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have done plenty of tests and research on this, but I simply cannot figure it out. I have a function that works perfectly fine when running locally (no errors), but fails when deployed as AWS lambda.

I created a simple example that recreates it:

**URL LOCAL**: http://localhost:3000/flagTest/visible (this works fine ✅)

**URL DEPLOYED AS LAMBDA**: https://www.publicfaq.com/flagTest/visible (the Toggle button doesn't work ❌)

**FILE**: /pages/flagTest/[tid].js (on a barebone NextJS installation)

```
import React from 'react'


class FlagTest extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps({ query }) {

    return { visible: query.tid }

  }

  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
      showFlag:false,
    }

  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({ showFlag: this.props.visible === 'visible'  });
  }

  handleToggle =()=> {

    this.setState({
      showFlag:!this.state.showFlag
    });
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Flag: {this.state.showFlag ? '' : ''} </h1>

        <button className='list_toggle' onClick={this.handleToggle}>
          {this.state.showFlag ? 'Hide Flag': 'Show Flag'}
        </button>

        <hr/>

        Props:
        <pre>
          {JSON.stringify(this.props, null, 2)}
        </pre>
        State:
        <pre>
          {JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2)}
        </pre>

      </div>
    );

  }
}

export default FlagTest
```

Note: I do need to use `getInitialProps` because I'm planning to use it in a more complex case (API Fetching by id), didn't included it here because is not directly related with this problem.

**This is my Serverless YML**

```
service: A123-serverless

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: ${self:custom.secrets.NODE_ENV}
  region: us-west-2
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: ${self:custom.secrets.NODE_ENV}

functions:
  server:
    handler: index.server
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: ANY /{proxy+}

plugins:
  - serverless-apigw-binary
  - serverless-domain-manager

custom:
  secrets: ${file(secrets.json)}
  apigwBinary:
    types:
      - '*/*'
  customDomain:
    domainName: ${self:custom.secrets.DOMAIN}
    basePath: ''
    stage: ${self:custom.secrets.NODE_ENV}
    createRoute53Record: true
    endpointType: 'regional'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem, posting it here, hopefully will help someone with the same problem:

The Problem was that I was using "query" to extract the 'id', It was working fine in local, but in the Server Side using Express you need to pass that as a parameter like this:

```
server.get("/q/:id", (req, res) => {
  return app.render(req, res, "/q/_tid", { id: req.params.id });
});
```

Then on the React component you can catch it and use it getInitial Props as `req.params.id`

```
static async getInitialProps({ req }) {

      myId = req.params.id

}
```